# responsiv bg on mobile

Tags: css, background

i' m making a website with a parallax on the start page background 
it' s working well when im resizing it on destock but when i'm on mobile the background is not resize it s look like the background is still the same than in big screen:

```css
/* Start page */

.start-page{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:10;
  background:url('../img/background/start-page.jpg') #c0c0c0 bottom center fixed no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.start-page hr{
  color: white;
  margin-top:30px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 1px;
  width:106px;
  border:0;

}

.start-page .opacity{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(51,51,51,0.5); /* Standard Off */
}


.start-page .content{
  position:relative;
  width:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
}

.start-page .content .text{
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  top:0; 
  left:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  right:0;
  width:700px;
  height:520px;
}

.start-page .content .text .logo{
  width:195px;
  height:153px;
  margin:0 auto 50px;
  
}

.start-page .content .text .read-more{
  width:183px;
  height:47px;
  margin:100px auto;
  line-height:47px;
  border:1px solid white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  background:none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
}

.start-page .content .text .read-more:hover{
  color:white;
  background:#ad2503;
  border:1px solid #ad2503;
}

.start-page .content .arrow-down{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 110px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 29px;
  background: url(../img/arrow-down.png) no-repeat center center;
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: bounce-fade 1.2s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    bounce-fade 1.2s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      bounce-fade 1.2s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
   animation:        bounce-fade 1.2s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}






@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 579px) {



.start-page {
  background: url('../img/background/start-pagemin.png') #c0c0c0 center center fixed no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
}
.start-page .content {
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
}

.start-page, .start-page .opacity{
  height:100%;
}
.start-page .content .text {
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<div class="container">


<!-- section start-page -->

  <div class="start-page parallax-background" id="home">

    <div class="opacity"></div> <!-- Opacity color -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="text">
        
          <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
        
        
          
         
          
        </div>
```

i dont know the snippet is looking like not work
but my problem is just that what i have to do into the media queries for get my background resize

Comment: We need code to help you.  This is not a specific question.

Comment: LOL a 160 line JavaScript snippet. Good luck with this.

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please reduce your snippet to just the sections that are relevant to this problem? Also can you elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: yes sorry its done ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I think you need the [viewport meta tag](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972). iOS assumes your page is 980px wide and shrinks everything to fit unless you include this, which would make all of your content appear smaller.

Comment: no i add it already  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">